# How do I run an if statement to find a specific file or folder using file.cFileName

Tags: c++

**For an example I want to find a specific folder named "DATABASE" in the %APPDATA% directory.**

I tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    string path = getenv("appdata");
    path += "\\*";

    WIN32_FIND_DATA file;
    HANDLE search_handle = FindFirstFile(path.c_str(), &file);

    if (search_handle){
        do{
            cout << file.cFileName << endl; // Prints all the files/folders in %appdata%
        }while (FindNextFile(search_handle, &file));
    }

    // Real Problem Below. . .

    if(file.cFileName == "DATABASE"){ // Doesn't work
        cout << "Folder Found! << endl;
    }else{
        cout << "Error: Folder not found. << endl;
    }


    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

*it doesn't do what I want it to do, is there a different way to do this?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't Java or C#.  The == operator for an array compared to a pointer doesn't work that way.

If you look at the definition of the cFileName member, it is this:

```
TCHAR    cFileName[MAX_PATH];
```

Depending on whether you built for Unicode or MBCS, TCHAR is either a WCHAR or a char.

If you really want to do a compare, use _tcsicmp().  I say to use _tcsicmp() instead of _tcscmp() because in Windows, file names are case insensitive.  Your problem line of code could be resolved like this:

```
if(0 ==_tcsicmp(file.cFileName, _T("DATABASE"))){ // works now
```

_tcsicmp() is the TCHAR equivalent of stricmp().  In general, if you create a new project in Visual C++, it usually enables Unicode strings.

Comment: Thank you! :)

Finally got it.